# How do you create something like a c# windows forms app that runs an all (desktop) platforms?

Tags: c#, user-interface, window, cross-platform

I want to make a c# desktop app that runs on at least Mac and Windows. I use Mac. Is this even possible? I am not sure how do this, I have only found these options:

c# console application - This is close but I want to be able to have it open a window and have buttons, input fields etc. Im not sure how to do that.

Xamarian Forms - This seems to only work for Mac and mobile platforms

Mono - I have heard of Mono, Visual Studio for Mac says it is built on it and can be used to make cross-platform applications. How does it work? How do I use it? Is it just for the console application to work?

Thank you for any info you can provide.

Comment: Check these two links - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/using-on-macos,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/using-on-mac-vs

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a visual editor for mac and windows alike, but using a library like Gtk# is working fine for me and allows me to make a gui application